# Behat unable to find my context classes

Tags: php, behat

I have a  features folder is the root directory, and inside a sub directory I have folder called public with 2 feature context classes. SignIn.php and PostProject.php

I specified the paths to the context classes in  the behat.yml file and it keeps telling me that the context class is not found and cannot be used? I really don't get how its unable to find it.

I am not sure how to correct this problem... It looks correct to me, and not sure what am I doing wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated. Below is my behat.yml file

```
default:
    suites:
        public:
            paths:      [%paths.base%/features/public]
            contexts:
                - PostProject
                - SignIn
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
    extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension:
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

The context classes needs to be autoloaded by its namespaces. And it needs to be specified in the behat.yml file. The paths context is used for the feature tests (test.feature) files

Here is the revised .yml file

```
default:
    autoload:
        '': %paths.base%/features
    suites:
        public:
            paths:      [%paths.base%/features]
            contexts:
                - public1\PostProject
                - public1\SignIn
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
        client:
            paths:      [%paths.base%/features]
            contexts:
                - Client
    extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension:
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
```

Example of the context classes

```
namespace public1;

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class SignIn  implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
//Content here
}



namespace public1;

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class PostProject  implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
//Content here
}
```